# Similar matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\text{If A = }
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & x  
  \end{bmatrix} \text{  is similar to B = } \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & y & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1  
  \end{bmatrix} \text{ Find x and y}
$$

My attempt:

Since A,B are simular then $tr(A) = tr(B)$

$tr(A) = 2 + x$

$tr(B) = 1 + y$

Therefore $2 + x = 1 + y$

$$|A - \lambda I | = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 - \lambda & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -\lambda & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & x-\lambda  
  \end{bmatrix} = (2-\lambda)(x + \lambda^2 - 1)
$$

I don't know what to do now. Could someone help me?

Comment: As you rightly proceeded, keep in mind that similar matrices have the same determinant, same trace, same characteristic polynomial (and hence same eigenvalues) and the same rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: their determinants are also the same.

Comment: Huge hint thx. $det(A) = 2(-1) = 2$, $det(B) = -2y$. Therefore y = 1? And using the trace's equation i get x = 0.